# how to Using bash to generate random IPs in Curl

Tags: bash, shell, curl

How to use random ip address in Curl request,I'm using this code in Curl But return my local ip from  http://ifconfig.me

```
printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))"
```

in Curl

```
curl --header 'X-Forwarded-For: printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))"' http://ifconfig.me
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're quoting incorrectly. You can try:

```
curl --header "X-Forwarded-For: $(printf "%d.%d.%d.%d" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))")"
```

You can get rid of the inner quotes and even the `printf` entirely:

```
curl --header "X-Forwarded-for: $((RANDOM % 256)).$((RANDOM % 256)).$((RANDOM % 256)).$((RANDOM % 256))"
```

However, whether the target site accepts the `X-Forwarded-For` is another matter entirely. Setting this header does not actually hide your own IP from the target site.

Comment: Is it possible to change the IP of this method for the target site? Or is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest this design

```
shuf -i 0-255 -rn4 | paste -sd.
```

But it loses `printf` since the first value in IP should not be equal to 0

```
printf %d.%d.%d.%d $((RANDOM%255+1)) $((RANDOM%256)){,,}
```

First the shell opens the "Brace Extension" and then substitutes the values of the variables

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Drat, right.  I will rewrite.  224, not 192

Comment: While you are correct that the first byte of an IPv4 address should not be 0, it should also not be 224 or larger as well (multicast and reserved). Thus, the first is `$((RANDOM%223+1))`  One might also exclude the first byte of 10 (private use) or 127 (localhost), but this requires some more complex code

Answer (score 1):

You forgot python:

```
$ python3 -c 'import ipaddress; import random; print( str( ipaddress.IPv4Address( random.randint( 0, 4294967295 ) ) ) )'
```

in your case

```
$ curl --header "X-Forwarded-For: $( python3 -c 'import ipaddress; import random; print( str( ipaddress.IPv4Address( random.randint( 0, 4294967295 ) ) ) )' )"  http://ifconfig.me
```

There are many pretty options. See `help( ipaddress )`. You could check `is_global`, `is_loopback`, `is_ipv6`, `is_subnet`, etcetera...